# Android Studio 4.0 - having issue adding a JAR file to app/libs folder

Tags: java, android

I am trying to add a JAR file into my Android build.  I did a copy/paste of the JAR file into the app/libs folder in Android Studio.  A quick look-up on how to next integrate indicated I then need to right-click on the jar file and select "Add as library".  Strangely enough, this option does not show up.  As a result, when I try to import the class, it says package not found.  (Even odder, I tried it earlier today on a different JAR file and the "Add as library" option showed up and then I could import the package). It seems I need to set things up so the "Add as library" option appears when right-clicking on the JAR file after copy/paste.  But how to make it so?

PS - I did see some slightly relevant stackoverflow posts on this, however, they are farther back in time and Android Studio has changed quite a bit since.

Thanks.

Comment: All you need is one line in your `dependencies` list in your module's `build.gradle` file: `implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])`. Usually, this is set up by default when you create a new Android Studio project.

Comment: A more accurate title is:  "Android Studio: Having issue integrating JAR file as a new library".

Comment: Maybe the JAR is corrupt or a newer Java version... can you unzip it??

Comment: I do see this line in the app/src/build.gradle file.  However, I still can not get the "Add as Library" option upon right-clicking the JAR file.

Comment: I just tried unzip on the JAR and it looks OK, indicating its contents to be a class and one binary file I cross-compiled to run on Google Pixel.  The java version I'm using is 1.8.0_252.

Comment: If you have that line in there and the file in the proper location, it should already be added. One binary file is a little less, because it may only be ARM or ARM64; usually it's four platforms (x86 is useful for emulation). With the Java version I rather meant the version which the JAR had been compiled with. I'd assume the one JAR is not properly packaged in some way, so that AS could recognize it on "Add as Library" (where it likely checks for the `MANIFEST.MF`). If this should be the case, only building from source could help.

Comment: Interestingly, this all started for me when I realized in Android 10.0, that one could no longer "exec" a binary file in the "home dir", like com.example.myapplication.  This prompted me to create a lib with java code that would call my cross-compiled (for x86) binary.  As you mention, when I created the AVD, it was recommended to employ an x86-based device, as it would execute code much faster than  ARM-based.  (I assume this holds for the physical device and not just the emulator?).  Anyway, my jar is built with   java-8 (openjdk-amd64).  And the JAR file does have a MANIFEST.MF file.

Comment: one unrelated item which just jumped out at me: when I unzipped the JAR, it showed the binary file to be non-executable, which will be a problem when it is called in the Android APK... The binary file is executable when I generate the JAR.